# SELECT DISTINCT filegroups and the total free space across multiple mountpoints (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql

I am trying to write a query which is able to calculate the possible free space for database filegroups.
I have a @table which contains the following info (this is filtered for 1 db only):

[image]

The column *'free_space'* is calculated one to show the total free space in a file having in mind if the file has autogrow and the size of the mountpoint where its located.

From this table I am trying to do a select which will return me a result for all databases and their filegroups calculating the free space for them across different mount points.

Example: if 1 database has all its files on one disk - to return the free space for this disk; If it has its files on more than one disk - to return the free space for the two (or more) disks; (the free space for each file is in the table above).

So far I am here:

```
SELECT
database_name
,groupid
,groupname
,SUM(file_size) as file_size
 --- The next two do the same thing;
,SUM(free_space) / (count (*) * 1.0) as free_space
,AVG(free_space)
,mount_point
FROM @file_size
--where database_name = 'kosevk'
GROUP BY mount_point, database_name, groupname
ORDER BY database_name
```

This runs okay until I add one more file on a different disk (example is file kosevk_data7 on disk G:) - then it returns two rows for PRIMARY filegroup.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pwDLnj1.png]

**I need to have each filegroup listed only once.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove mount_point from the GROUP BY clause and comment out mount_point in the select as below.

Hopefully it will help you.

SELECT
database_name
,groupid
,groupname
,SUM(file_size) as file_size
 --- The next two do the same thing;
,SUM(free_space) / (count (*) * 1.0) as free_space
,AVG(free_space)
--,mount_point
FROM @file_size
--where database_name = 'kosevk'
GROUP BY database_name, groupname
ORDER BY database_name

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be the query :

```
;With CTE AS (SELECT
database_name
,groupid
,groupname
,SUM(file_size) as file_size
 --- The next two do the same thing;
,SUM(free_space) / (count (*) * 1.0) as free_space
,AVG(free_space)
,mount_point
FROM @file_size)
select database_name, sum(file_size), sum(free_space), mount_point
group by database_name, mount_point
```